# Part of the relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> The injury which all surgeons thought was incurable took away the victims life.

What is the relative clause of this sentence?

**which all surgeons thought** was incruable.
Is **was curable** also part of this relative clause?

My books say relative pronoun will serve as subject or object in the clause,
if **which all surgeons thought was incurable** is the relative clause,
Since **which** is behind the verb and is in front of be verb **was**,
Should **which** act as the subject or the object?

Answer (score 1):

> *The injury* [*which all surgeons thought* [ ____ *was incurable*]] *took away the*
>   *victims life*.

The constituent in outer brackets is the relative clause.

The relative pronoun "which" functions as subject of the embedded "was" clause in inner brackets within the relative clause :

We understand that all surgeons thought (that) the injury was incurable.